# How to see foreign CNAME records pointing to my domain

Tags: dns, alias, cname

Is there a way to figure out what domains are redirected by DNS to my domain?

Example:

I own foobar.org

Someone creates an CNAME record named hidden.org that points to foobar.org

I don't know that this record / alias exists, yet.

How do I find out?

Comment: hi this CNAME are pointing to a cloud server?

Comment: @headmax Yes, but does this make a difference?